# Why can't I iterate over all the elements returned by getElementsByTagName?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to replace a group of tags with another tag, but for some reason I can't seem to loop over all the tags that getElementsByTagName() returns.

[In the example](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/dxNmG/1/) the second `td` in the first row is skipped for some reason even though it shows up in the `console.log(tds)`.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup **in the question itself**, don't just link. Links rot, and people shouldn't have to follow links to help you. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: (Having looked at the link) You can't replace `td` elements with `b` elements, the result is an invalid DOM structure (`tr` cannot directly contain `b`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I would rather have posted the code - but people seem to get mad that I don't post fiddles so I did. :P

Comment: @ Xeoncross: It's a both/and thing, not an either/or thing. Posting the code *in* the question is not optional. A fiddle *as well* is a nice adjunct, but not a requirement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the first line to:

```
var tds = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td'), 0);
```

The value returned from `.getElementsByTagName()` is a NodeList, not an array. NodeList objects are "live", which means that they change as you change the DOM.  That is, `tds.length` is decrementing, but your `i` is incrementing as well - thus you're missing an element each iteration.  If you turn it into an array first, as above, then your code should work.

Comment: "Why" would be nice, as well as an explanation of what's happening.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's there now - I don't type as fast as you :-)

Comment: @pimvdb thanks!  I was going to add what you added but I had to double-check in the fiddle first because I always get descriptions of those situations backwards!

Comment: If that is the case, is there any reason to change this to an array to begin with - or should I just iterate over the NodeList object?

Comment: You can iterate over the NodeList if you want to, @Xeoncross - the node to operate on will always be the first one in the list, because once you change it to a `<b>` it'll disappear.